# If the internal angle bisectors of $\triangle ABC$ meet its circumcircle at $D$, $E$, $F$, then what is the area of $\triangle DEF$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, triangles

> If the internal angle bisectors of $\triangle ABC$ meet its circumcircle at $D$, $E$, $F$, then what is the area of $\triangle DEF$?

For the solution of this question in my book, it is written 
$$\begin{align}
\text{area of}\;\triangle DEF &= \frac{|DE||EF||FD|}{4R} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{2R \sin\left(\dfrac{B+C}{2}\right)\cdot 2R \sin\left(\dfrac{C+A}{2}\right)\cdot2R \sin\left(\dfrac{A+B}{2}\right)}{4R}
\end{align}$$

I took this to imply that 
$$|DE|=2R \left(\dfrac{B+C}{2}\right),\quad |EF|= 2R \sin\left(\dfrac{C+A}{2}\right),\quad |FD|=2R \sin\left(\dfrac{A+B}{2}\right)$$

If this is true, where did they get the result from? Would someone please guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D$, $E$, $F$ are the intersections of the circumcircle with the bisectors of $A$, $B$, $C$ respectively, then 
$$
\angle ADE=\angle ABE=\angle ABC/2,
\quad 
\angle ADF=\angle ACF=\angle ACB/2,
$$
because they are subtended by the same arcs. Then use the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) to get
$$
EF=2R\sin(\angle EDF)=2R\sin(\angle ABC/2+\angle ACB/2).
$$